# Беспорядок с кодами клавиш при проверке нажатых клавиш в поле формы

Tags: события, javascript

Короче говоря, это уже мой второй вопрос на ту же тему. Пытаюсь написать код, который бы проверял нажатые пользователем клавиши в поле формы. Чтобы пропускал только символы русского, англ. алфавита и цифры. Обработчик привязал к событию **keypress** (keydown ведет себя безумным образом). Для совместимости с браузерами пришлось писать вот такой грязный код :

```
$('input').keypress(validateKeyPressInput);

function validateKeyPressInput(e){
 e = e || window.event;
 var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
 var char = String.fromCharCode(code);
 var t = /[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9]/.test(char);
 if (t) return true;
 //
 // проверяем, а не нажата ли функциональная клавиша
 //
 if(code == 8 || code == 37 
    || code == 39 || code == 9 || code == 46)
   return true;     
 return false;
}
```

Это все хорошо, вот только коды 37, 39 и 46 также относятся и к кодам символов %(процент),'(один.кавычка) и .(точка). То есть программный код пропускает эти символы как разрешенные. Как бороться с этой проблемой???

Comment: Что вам нужно от скрипта?

Comment: Чтобы скрипт вообще не выводил запрещенные символы в поле формы. Сейчас он так и делает, но пропускает 3 вышеописанных символа

Comment: А уточните, пожалуйста, для чего вы пропускаете эти символы в вашем коде (`if(code == 8 || code == 37 ...`)?

Comment: @VladD, Уточняю - без этой строчки клавиши вперед-назад-бэкспейс НЕ работают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует различать `keyCode` и `charCode`. Вот пример, который отличает `%` от стрелки влево: http://jsfiddle.net/Hfa3t/

Проверял только на FF.

Документация: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: Хорошо, но все равно для клавиш со стрелками и бэкспейс нужно делать отдельную проверку!

Comment: @Deus: ну, вы можете просто разрешить charcode = 0, нет?

Comment: @VladD, ну конечно!

Answer (score 2):

Уберите отдельную проверку на функциональные клавиши. Код отлично работает без неё: http://jsfiddle.net/9qkYh/2/. Проверено в Chrome/Firefox/IE9.

Comment: @fori1ton, запустил в firefox - не работают клавиши вперед-назад-бэкспейс

Comment: Поправочка: [http://jsfiddle.net/9qkYh/3/][1]. Если `charCode == 0`, то нажата клавиша с непечатным символом. Спасибо @Vlad за наводку.

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/9qkYh/3/

Answer (score 0):

Я же и отвечу, но жду более адекватного ответа. Поменял событие keypress на keydown, однако добавил проверку на цифровые клавиши, ибо для браузера одинаково - что символ "3", что "#'

```
$('input').keydown(validateKeyPressInput);

function validateKeyPressInput(e){
 e = e || window.event;
 var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
 var char = String.fromCharCode(code);
 var t = /[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]/.test(char);
 if (t) return true;
 // Проверим, а не нажата ли цифровая клавиша БЕЗ shift
 if (code >= 48 && code <=57 && !e.shiftKey) return true;
 //
 // проверяем, а не нажата ли функциональная клавиша
 //
 if(code == 8 || code == 37 
    || code == 39 || code == 9 || code == 46)
   return true;     
 return false;
}
```